# Cannot start standalone instance of HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, java-home

I was unable to configure the HBase standalone instance. Following are the steps I followed:

1. Downloaded `hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2` and extracted it.
2. Set my `JAVA_HOME`in the environment variables.
3. Edited `conf/hbase-site.xml` and changed the configuration as mentioned in the Apache HBase quick start guide.
4. Ran the `bin/start-hbase.sh` and this error came up.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps: 
http://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html

Hbase cannot be installed without cygwin tooling.

Comment: Please add the steps to your answer instead of just referencing a website which might disappear later.

Comment: The link is the official documentation on how to install HBase on windows, and maintained by HBase project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in the HBase standalone installation [guide](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart), it doesn't mention cygwin anywhere

Comment: HBase installation has quite a few prerequisites, most of which are difficult to install without cygwin. See http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#basic.prerequisites 
Though I can't be sure as I haven't installed hbase on windows, (and don't know of anyone who has), I think you will have an easier time installing and working with HBase using cygwin than without.

Comment: Well I managed to start Hbase in standalone mode. As it turned out, HMaster was not running! So I downloaded a previous version in my case **hbase-0.94.26**, DID NOT do the configuration in 'hbase-site.xml', and simply ran 'start-hbase.sh'. Then ran it again to make sure that HMaster was running.
And in this case I was using Linux. Btw thanks for your help :)

Comment: @as77 I'm now going to configure HBase using cygwin in Windows. Acutally I'm trying to use the HBase API in java and play around with it. So I prefer to use it on Windows where I can use it in eclipse easily